# SQLAlchemy poor performance on iterating

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

The following block of code queries a table with ~2000 rows. The loop takes 20s to execute! From my limited knowledge, I don't think I'm doing 2000 queries, just the one, but perhaps I'm not understanding the '.' operator and what it's doing behind the scenes. How can I fix this loop to run more quickly? Is there a way to adjust the top level query s.t. the 2nd for loop is not making a total of 3000 queries (if that's in fact what's going on)?

Here is a test block of code I made to verify that it was in fact this inner loop that was causing the massive time consumption.

```
block = []
cnt = 0
for blah in dbsession.query(mytable):
    tic = time.time()
    for a in blah.component:
        cnt += 1
    block.append(time.time()-tic)
print "block: %s seconds    cnt: %s" % (sum(block), cnt)

# block: 20.78191 seconds    cnt: 3021
```

Using the suggestion from the selected best-answer, the for loop became:

```
for blah in dbsession.query(mytable).options( joinedload(mytable.componentA)).options(mytable.componentB)).options(mytable.componentC)
```

which resulted in the inner loops of each component going from 20-25s each, to 0.25 0.59 and 0.11s respectively. The query itself now takes about 18s ... so my total saved time is about 55s.

Comment: What is `blah.component`? A column? A relationship?

Comment: "I don't think I'm doing 2000 queries": you should enable logging or pass `echo=True` to engine.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with DBs, but I believe a relationship. It's listed in orm.mapper( a, b, properties = {'component': orm.relationship(othercomponent, secondary=<blah>, primaryjoin=<blah>==<blah>, secondaryjoin=<blah>==<blah>})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you access `.component` another SQL query is emitted.

You can read more at [Relationship Loading Techniques](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html), but to load it all at once you can change your query to the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload

dbsession.query(mytable).options(joinedload('component'))
```

Comment: would the for loop become: for blah, blahcomponent in dbsession.query...?

Comment: No, just `for blah in dbsession.query(...`, SQLAlchemy knows that when you then access `.component` that it is already loaded.

Comment: words cannot even begin to express my gratitude ... 21s to 0.37s

Comment: if i have multiple relationships to load, do i do options(joinedload(mytable.componentx).joinedload(mytable.componenty))?

Comment: No, you do `options(joinedload(mytable.componentx), joinedload(mytable.componenty))`. The method chaining is for nested relationships.